How to Upload Files to External API using Use Server with NextJS 14
[HEADS UP]: I'm required to use a Server Page, othetwise I would I have used "client side" component with axios.
I'm trying to upload a file to my external express server. Whatsoever, when sending it to the API route, the req.files.file is empty, undefined or simply blank.
I'd like to mention the file is detected when the action attribute is triggered after submitting the form. The console.log(avatar) returns the following:
file: File {
  size: 476026,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'Delta-Force-Operator-in-a-Chinook_4x-scaled.jpg',
  lastModified: 1716527617781
}

Whatsoever, the troubles I'm facing have to do with the Express server. I use a library called express-fileupload and in order to get the files from the upcoming request, I need to do something like req.files.file where file is the name of your input.
exports.uploadObject = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Prevent execution of code if there is not file in request
  console.dir(req.files);
  
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0 || !req.files.file) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`No file uploaded`, 400));
  }

  /*
  YADAYADAYADA
  */
      // Return object
      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        data: "success"
      });
    });
  });
});

The issue
No matter what I do, the server does not receive the file and this is what gets displayed on the terminal {}, an actual emptpy object with not even field or values in it.
This is my form within a Server Page:
const upgradeAvatar = async (formData) => {
  'use server'
  const avatar = formData.get('file')

  const rawFormData = {
    userId: auth?.data?._id,
    username: auth?.data?.username,
    userEmail: auth?.data?.email,
    onModel: 'User',
    album: 'profile-avatars',
    file: avatar,
  }
  // Output
  console.log(rawFormData.file);
  // My function to external API
  await uploadFile(rawFormData)
}

<form action={upgradeAvatar}>
  <label htmlFor="file" className="form-label">
    File
  </label>
  <input
    id="file"
    name="file"
    type="file"
    className="form-control mb-3"
    accept={`image/*`}
  />
  <FormButtons />
</form>



In the end I was not able to implement what I wanted to do, so I decided to create a secondary file where I put all the form's logic and the Api request as well.
'use client'
import { fetchurl, getAuthTokenOnServer } from '@/helpers/setTokenOnServer'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import Image from 'next/image'
import UseProgress from '@/components/global/useprogress'
import axios from 'axios'

const Form = ({ auth }) => {
  const [coverData, setCoverData] = useState({
    file: null,
    filename: `Choose file`,
    fileurl: `https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/005/337/799/original/icon-image-not-found-free-vector.jpg`,
  })

  const { file, filename, fileurl } = coverData

  const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [btnText, setBtnTxt] = useState('Submit')

  const upgradeAvatar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setBtnTxt('Submit...')
    const token = await getAuthTokenOnServer()
    const res = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/uploads/uploadobject`,
      {
        userId: auth?.data?._id,
        username: auth?.data?.username,
        userEmail: auth?.data?.email,
        onModel: 'User',
        file: file,
        album: 'profile-covers',
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token.value}`,
        },
        onUploadProgress: (ProgressEvent) => {
          setUploadPercentage(
            parseInt(
              Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total
            )
          )
          setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 10000)
        },
      }
    )
    await fetchurl(`/auth/updateavatar`, 'PUT', 'no-cache', {
      cover: res.data.data._id,
    })
  }

  const resetForm = () => {
    setCoverData({
      file: null,
      filename: `Choose file`,
      fileurl: `https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/005/337/799/original/icon-image-not-found-free-vector.jpg`,
    })
  }

  return (
      <form onSubmit={upgradeAvatar}>
        <label htmlFor="cover" className="form-label">
          File
        </label>
        <input
          id="cover"
          name="file"
          label={file}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const myFile = e.target.files[0]
            let preview = ''
            if (myFile instanceof Blob || myFile instanceof File) {
              preview = URL.createObjectURL(myFile)
            }
            setCoverData({
              file: myFile,
              filename: myFile.name,
              fileurl: preview,
            })
          }}
          type="file"
          className="form-control mb-3"
          placeholder={fileurl}
          accept={`image/*`}
        />
        <UseProgress percentage={uploadPercentage} />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-start">
          {btnText}
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-end"
          onClick={resetForm}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </form>
  )
}

export default Form

and then I simply called the Form component to my server page.
import { fetchurl } from '@/helpers/setTokenOnServer'
import Form from './form'

async function getAuthenticatedUser() {
  const res = await fetchurl(`/auth/me`, 'GET', 'no-cache')
  return res
}

const UpdateAvatar = async ({ params, searchParams }) => {
  const auth = await getAuthenticatedUser()

  // Redirect if user is not logged in
  ;(auth?.error?.statusCode === 401 || !auth?.data?.isOnline) &&
    redirect(`/auth/login`)

  return <Form auth={auth} />
}

export default UpdateAvatar

